# open,edit and save xml file with schema using php

Tags: php, xml

Hy... I'm new in XML Schema, XSL,... (I have basic understanding)
On web page: http://w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_editxml.asp
is shown example for open,edit,save xml file, but with asp.
Do anyone know how can i open/edit and save xml file using php for next example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<tools>
 <tool id="1">
  <field id="prodName">
    <value>HAMMER HG2606</value>
  </field>
  <field id="prodNo">
    <value>32456240</value>
  </field>
  <field id="price">
    <value>$30.00</value>
  </field>
 </tool>
<tool id="2">
  <field id="prodName">
    <value>Audi</value>
  </field>
  <field id="prodNo">
    <value>88885</value>
  </field>
  <field id="price">
    <value>$26.00</value>
  </field>
 </tool>
</tools>
```

and do i need `<tool id="2">` or just `<tool>` is enough.
Thanks very much on replay, and i don't need another xsl like shown on w3s, just fine is refresh submitted php file after submit (will do something with ajax after).

I saw replay from Mr. Writman on questions/377632/add-update-and-edit-an-xml-file-with-php
but that is for now 2 complex for me...:) is there any simpler answer (solution). Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

To validate the XML against a Schema file you can use

- [`DOMDocument::schemaValidate`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php)  —  Validates a document based on a schema
- [`DOMDocument::schemaValidateSource`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidatesource.php)  —  Validates a document based on a schema

Example:

```
$document = DOMDocument::load('books.xml');

if ($document->schemaValidate('books.xsd')) {
  print 'books.xml does validate against books.xsd';
}
```

Also see these methods and the examples given on their manual pages:

- [`DOMDocument::load`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) —  Load XML from a file
- [`DOMDocument::getElementById`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)  — Searches for an element with a certain id
- [`DOMDocument::save`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) —  Dumps the internal XML tree back into a file

You will find XML manipulation with DOM covered extensively at SO:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DOM+php

Comment: Thanks... Will check is there everything i'm interest in.